# Segmentation fault with fftpack

Tags: fortran, runtime-error, gfortran, fftpack

I'm trying to use the fftpack (specifically rffti.f, rffti1.f, rfftf.f, rfftf1.f, radf4.f, radf2.f, radf3.f, radf5.f, radfg.f) downloaded from https://www.netlib.org/fftpack/index.html with this test code:

```
program test
implicit none
integer,parameter:: n=100
real,dimension(n):: x,y
integer:: i 
real:: pi = 3.1415923535

x= [(i, i=1,n)]
y= sin((2*pi/100)*x)

call RFFTI(100,y)

end program test
```

,compiling and running with:

```
gfortran -Wall -Wextra -o program.out \
rffti.f rffti1.f rfftf.f rfftf1.f radf4.f radf2.f radf3.f radf5.f radfg.f test.f90

./program.out
```

, and I get this runtime error:

Program received signal SIGSEGV: Segmentation fault - invalid memory reference.

Backtrace for this error:
do.sh: line 6:  9069 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) ./program.out

Apart from that error I get these warnings:

```
rffti1.f:8:72:

    8 |       IF (J-4) 102,102,103
      |                                                                        1
Warning: Fortran 2018 deleted feature: Arithmetic IF statement at (1)
rffti1.f:14:72:

   14 |       IF (NR) 101,105,101
      |                                                                        1
Warning: Fortran 2018 deleted feature: Arithmetic IF statement at (1)
rffti1.f:24:11:

   24 |       IFAC(3) = 2
      |           1
Warning: Array reference at (1) is out of bounds (3 > 1) in dimension 1
rffti1.f:27:11:

   27 |       IFAC(2) = NF
      |           1
Warning: Array reference at (1) is out of bounds (2 > 1) in dimension 1
rffti1.f:35:19:

   34 |       DO 110 K1=1,NFM1
      |                                                                        2
   35 |          IP = IFAC(K1+2)
      |                   1
Warning: Array reference at (1) out of bounds (3 > 1) in loop beginning at (2)
rfftf1.f:3:16:

    3 |       NF = IFAC(2)
      |                1
Warning: Array reference at (1) is out of bounds (2 > 1) in dimension 1
radf4.f:13:72:

   13 |       IF (IDO-2) 107,105,102
      |                                                                        1
Warning: Fortran 2018 deleted feature: Arithmetic IF statement at (1)
radf4.f:18:43:

   16 |          DO 103 I=3,IDO,2
      |                                                                        2
   17 |             IC = IDP2-I
   18 |             CR2 = WA1(I-2)*CC(I-1,K,2)+WA1(I-1)*CC(I,K,2)
      |                                           1
Warning: Array reference at (1) out of bounds (2 > 1) in loop beginning at (2)
radf4.f:19:41:

   16 |          DO 103 I=3,IDO,2
      |                                                                        2
......
   19 |             CI2 = WA1(I-2)*CC(I,K,2)-WA1(I-1)*CC(I-1,K,2)
      |                                         1
Warning: Array reference at (1) out of bounds (2 > 1) in loop beginning at (2)
radf4.f:20:43:

   16 |          DO 103 I=3,IDO,2
      |                                                                        2
......
   20 |             CR3 = WA2(I-2)*CC(I-1,K,3)+WA2(I-1)*CC(I,K,3)
      |                                           1
Warning: Array reference at (1) out of bounds (2 > 1) in loop beginning at (2)
radf4.f:21:41:

   16 |          DO 103 I=3,IDO,2
      |                                                                        2
......
   21 |             CI3 = WA2(I-2)*CC(I,K,3)-WA2(I-1)*CC(I-1,K,3)
      |                                         1
Warning: Array reference at (1) out of bounds (2 > 1) in loop beginning at (2)
radf4.f:22:43:

   16 |          DO 103 I=3,IDO,2
      |                                                                        2
......
   22 |             CR4 = WA3(I-2)*CC(I-1,K,4)+WA3(I-1)*CC(I,K,4)
      |                                           1
Warning: Array reference at (1) out of bounds (2 > 1) in loop beginning at (2)
radf4.f:23:41:

   16 |          DO 103 I=3,IDO,2
      |                                                                        2
......
   23 |             CI4 = WA3(I-2)*CC(I,K,4)-WA3(I-1)*CC(I-1,K,4)
      |                                         1
Warning: Array reference at (1) out of bounds (2 > 1) in loop beginning at (2)
radf2.f:8:72:

    8 |       IF (IDO-2) 107,105,102
      |                                                                        1
Warning: Fortran 2018 deleted feature: Arithmetic IF statement at (1)
radf2.f:13:43:

   11 |          DO 103 I=3,IDO,2
      |                                                                        2
   12 |             IC = IDP2-I
   13 |             TR2 = WA1(I-2)*CC(I-1,K,2)+WA1(I-1)*CC(I,K,2)
      |                                           1
Warning: Array reference at (1) out of bounds (2 > 1) in loop beginning at (2)
radf2.f:14:41:

   11 |          DO 103 I=3,IDO,2
      |                                                                        2
......
   14 |             TI2 = WA1(I-2)*CC(I,K,2)-WA1(I-1)*CC(I-1,K,2)
      |                                         1
Warning: Array reference at (1) out of bounds (2 > 1) in loop beginning at (2)
radf3.f:16:43:

   14 |          DO 102 I=3,IDO,2
      |                                                                        2
   15 |             IC = IDP2-I
   16 |             DR2 = WA1(I-2)*CC(I-1,K,2)+WA1(I-1)*CC(I,K,2)
      |                                           1
Warning: Array reference at (1) out of bounds (2 > 1) in loop beginning at (2)
radf3.f:17:41:

   14 |          DO 102 I=3,IDO,2
      |                                                                        2
......
   17 |             DI2 = WA1(I-2)*CC(I,K,2)-WA1(I-1)*CC(I-1,K,2)
      |                                         1
Warning: Array reference at (1) out of bounds (2 > 1) in loop beginning at (2)
radf3.f:18:43:

   14 |          DO 102 I=3,IDO,2
      |                                                                        2
......
   18 |             DR3 = WA2(I-2)*CC(I-1,K,3)+WA2(I-1)*CC(I,K,3)
      |                                           1
Warning: Array reference at (1) out of bounds (2 > 1) in loop beginning at (2)
radf3.f:19:41:

   14 |          DO 102 I=3,IDO,2
      |                                                                        2
......
   19 |             DI3 = WA2(I-2)*CC(I,K,3)-WA2(I-1)*CC(I-1,K,3)
      |                                         1
Warning: Array reference at (1) out of bounds (2 > 1) in loop beginning at (2)
radf5.f:22:43:

   20 |          DO 102 I=3,IDO,2
      |                                                                        2
   21 |             IC = IDP2-I
   22 |             DR2 = WA1(I-2)*CC(I-1,K,2)+WA1(I-1)*CC(I,K,2)
      |                                           1
Warning: Array reference at (1) out of bounds (2 > 1) in loop beginning at (2)
radf5.f:23:41:

   20 |          DO 102 I=3,IDO,2
      |                                                                        2
......
   23 |             DI2 = WA1(I-2)*CC(I,K,2)-WA1(I-1)*CC(I-1,K,2)
      |                                         1
Warning: Array reference at (1) out of bounds (2 > 1) in loop beginning at (2)
radf5.f:24:43:

   20 |          DO 102 I=3,IDO,2
      |                                                                        2
......
   24 |             DR3 = WA2(I-2)*CC(I-1,K,3)+WA2(I-1)*CC(I,K,3)
      |                                           1
Warning: Array reference at (1) out of bounds (2 > 1) in loop beginning at (2)
radf5.f:25:41:

   20 |          DO 102 I=3,IDO,2
      |                                                                        2
......
   25 |             DI3 = WA2(I-2)*CC(I,K,3)-WA2(I-1)*CC(I-1,K,3)
      |                                         1
Warning: Array reference at (1) out of bounds (2 > 1) in loop beginning at (2)
radf5.f:26:43:

   20 |          DO 102 I=3,IDO,2
      |                                                                        2
......
   26 |             DR4 = WA3(I-2)*CC(I-1,K,4)+WA3(I-1)*CC(I,K,4)
      |                                           1
Warning: Array reference at (1) out of bounds (2 > 1) in loop beginning at (2)
radf5.f:27:41:

   20 |          DO 102 I=3,IDO,2
      |                                                                        2
......
   27 |             DI4 = WA3(I-2)*CC(I,K,4)-WA3(I-1)*CC(I-1,K,4)
      |                                         1
Warning: Array reference at (1) out of bounds (2 > 1) in loop beginning at (2)
radf5.f:28:43:

   20 |          DO 102 I=3,IDO,2
      |                                                                        2
......
   28 |             DR5 = WA4(I-2)*CC(I-1,K,5)+WA4(I-1)*CC(I,K,5)
      |                                           1
Warning: Array reference at (1) out of bounds (2 > 1) in loop beginning at (2)
radf5.f:29:41:

   20 |          DO 102 I=3,IDO,2
      |                                                                        2
......
   29 |             DI5 = WA4(I-2)*CC(I,K,5)-WA4(I-1)*CC(I-1,K,5)
      |                                         1
Warning: Array reference at (1) out of bounds (2 > 1) in loop beginning at (2)
```

Comment: Please show the interface of `RFFTI`. Double-check that you are calling it correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RFFTI` is an initialization routine that prepares some work data to a special work array.

```
  SUBROUTINE RFFTI (N,WSAVE)
  DIMENSION       WSAVE(1)
```

The `(1)` is just an obsolete and very unfortunate way to write `(*)`.

You must read [the manual](https://www.netlib.org/fftpack/doc) and find out what size is the `WSAVE` array supposed to be. Please note that it is a special work array for internal data, it is NOT for your data that you want to transform.

From the manual:

> wsave
> a work array which must be dimensioned at least 2*n+15.
> the same work array can be used for both rfftf and rfftb
> as long as n remains unchanged. different wsave arrays
> are required for different values of n. the contents of
> wsave must not be changed between calls of rfftf or rfftb.

Comment: Thank you so much for the info, I get to solve the problem.